# Creating multiple-page reports in Access (new page for each group)

Tags: ms-access, report, ms-access-2013

I'm looking to create a report which is specifically designed to be over multiple pages, based on one condition. The condition is that when the grouped item (call it invoice) changes, it starts a new page, instead of putting all the data on as little pages as possible.

At the moment it runs like this,

```
Invoice, Date, ID
------------------
2      , Now , 1
------------------
3      , Now , 1
------------------
```

I want to insert a page break between the invoice numbers, but can't figure how to do it, is it possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the Group Header for "Invoice" on your report you can set the `Force New Page` property to `Before Section` to start each invoice on a new page. For details, see

[Print each group of your Access report on a separate page](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/microsoft-office/print-each-group-of-your-access-report-on-a-separate-page/)